# oracle table does not exist error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to generate a plsql script like this:

```
set serveroutput on format word_wrapped;
DECLARE

file_name     VARCHAR2(400);
varTemp   NUMBER;


BEGIN

file_name := 'data_oracle.csv';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE data_tmp (
  ID      NUMBER(25),
  CLASS    VARCHAR2(20),
  DATE DATE,
  VAL  NUMBER(25)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY USER_DIR
  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '',''
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    (
  ID,
  CLASS,
  DATE,
  VAL
    )
  )
  LOCATION (''' || file_name || ''')
)
PARALLEL 5
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tableTemp ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS SELECT a.ID,a.DATE,a.VAL,b.CLS,b.FEES,b.TYPE FROM data_tmp a, secondTable b WHERE a.CLASS = b.CLS AND (b.FEES < a.VAL)';

SELECT COUNT(1) INTO varTemp FROM tableTemp'; -- line 52
IF varTemp > 0 THEN

-- code to write query result to file
END IF;

END;
/
```

But I'm getting this exception:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) INTO varTemp FROM tableTemp;
                                     *
ERROR at line 52:
ORA-06550: line 52, column 38:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 52, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

But all the tables are being generated properly and data is being loaded.

Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong in line 52. Kindly help out a oracle newbie here.

Comment: By the way the standard SQL expression for counting is `count(*)`. Of course you can put your own random literals in place of `*` but the parser just has to replace them. Plus `*` is less to type on most keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

At compile time the table does not exist, you create it within the script. You would have to run the SELECT also as dynamic SQL

However, I would recommend to create the table only once with a static file name. If the file names on your file system are different consider to use symbolic links.

Also there is absolutely no need to create a GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE dynamically at run time. Content of such table is deleted anyway when the session ends.

I assume the reason why you try to create table `data_tmp` on the fly is because `file_name` is changing (perhaps the file name contains a time stamp of current day). In case the file name does not change there is no need for dynamic SQL at all!

Comment: dynamic SQL ??? Are you saying i should use `execute immediate` to execute line 52? could you just show me how the statement would look like then?

Comment: Also, symbolic links, could you elaborate a little bit on that?

Comment: Yes, `execute immediate 'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tableTemp' into INTO varTemp`

Comment: Regarding symbolic links: Use Google.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to include the creation of `GLOBAL TEMPORARY Table`, code to write query result to file, as a separate block of code, independent of original table creation. The reason being that it currently makes things harder to debug the code when it fails.

In other words,    `CREATE TABLE data_tmp..`  should be part of an independent one time sql script, that permanently creates the external table.
The problem with running everything in dynamic sql is that it converts compile time error into run-time errors, causing it to be less developer friendly for debugging.

Now, the problem in your case is that the anonymous block you are trying to run is compiled first to resolve all the dependencies. However, the TABLE `tableTemp` cannot be resolved at compile time because it is **NOT** created yet. One way to avoid this would be to include even this part in dynamic sql.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT (1) FROM tableTemp' INTO varTemp ;
```

When all is said and done, remember that the code you get eventually is less efficient and non-portable.